# Valores com tipos diferentes Gson - Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Eu gostaria de saber, se existe uma forma com Gson de obter valores de diferentes tipos em um array de "chave-valor" em Json.  Segue o exemplo:

```
{
"events":[
            {"event":"comprou-produto",
             "timestamp":"2016-09-22T13:57:32.2311892-03:00",
             "custom_data":[
                    {"key":"product_name","value":"Camisa Azul"},
                    {"key":"transaction_id","value":"3029384"},
                    {"key":"product_price","value":100}]} ... outros elementos]}
```

Neste exemplo acima temos o array "custom_data" com os campos de chave-valor, e repare que "product_price" é um campo e o seu valor é um double (ou int se preferir), sendo que os demais são Strings.  Como eu posso obter esses valores com Gson.  Eu fiz uma classe para tentar ler esse conjunto de dados.  Segue:

```
public class Event {

private final String event;
private final String timestamp;
private final double revenue;
private final List<CustomData> custom_data;

//Constructor.
public Event(String event, String timestamp, double revenue, List<CustomData> custom_data) {
    this.event = event;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.revenue = revenue;
    this.custom_data = custom_data;
}

//nested class.
public static class CustomData{

    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    public CustomData(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Obs: O campo revenue, refere-se a uma informação extra do conjunto de eventos que o array mais externo possuí, em alguns casos como o do exemplo eu simplesmente o ignoro.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um Map pra isso.

```
public class Event {
    ...
    private final List<Map<String, Object>> custom_data;
    ...
}
```

Parse:

```
EventWrapper events = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData,EventWrapper.class);
```

EventWrapper.java

```
public class EventWrapper {
    private Event[] events;

    public Event[] getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}
```

Acesso:

```
for (Map<String, Object> customData : event.getCustom_data()) {
    String chave = (String) customData.get("key");
    String valor = String.valueOf(customData.get("value"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s => %s", chave, valor));
}
```

Resultado:
[image: Screenshot das variaveis no debugger]

Parse:
EventWrapper events = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData,EventWrapper.class);

Comment: Você utilizou a API Gson pra poder obter esses dados ?  Eu estou com dúvida justamente em como fazer essa ação com o Gson.

Comment: Editei a resposta com como fiz a conversão